# How to instrument C++ program so that args & return values are stored?

Tags: c++11, debugging, gcc, instrumentation

I'm working on a C++11 embedded Linux application.  We currently use gcc-6.3.

What modifications would it take (and to what parts), so record all arguments passed into our C++ functions, and also their return values?

Modifying gcc is an option if that's the only way.

Comment: Where and how would you "record" the arguments?

Comment: Recording should be the easy part, once figuring out how to capture the data.  E.g. could just store it in a FIFO buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider extending GCC with a [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (or some extension in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)).

**This is not a trivial task** (could take weeks or more probably *months* of work), you'll need to understand the organization of [passes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html) and the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) representation. Look at some slides in http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html

You could annotate your functions to be traced with your own specific [custom attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins-attr.html) (read about [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) then add your [custom optimization pass](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins-pass.html) modifying the GIMPLE around calls to these functions. You'll probably want to insert a call to some logging function before and after such calls.

<sup>(I recommend to make your plugin free software, you might get help about it; be aware of the [GCC runtime library exception](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.en.html))</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Basile said, using [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) could be an option as well, especially if the instrumentation has to happen on demand and performance is less of a concern.

Comment: Systemtap looks like it would be less effort so I'll investigate this first, then look at the GCC plugin suggested above.